# How do I prevent segmentation fault when starting rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  I know there have been several forum topics mentioning the same problem I had but none of them seem to offer me the right solution, so here I am asking the question again.  After having created a workspace in ROS and sourcing the setup.bash file, I run 'rosdep install rviz'.  Once all the dependencies have been installed, I compile the package using 'rosmake rviz'.  The package builds successfully.  I then run 'rosrun rviz rviz' and get the following results (ignore the color coding):

---

```
sinhau@ubuntu:~/tf_tutorials$ rosrun rviz rviz

[ INFO] [1350587343.349569680]: rviz revision number 1.8.14
    
[ INFO] [1350587343.349747565]: compiles against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
    
[ INFO] [1350587343.378668970]: Loading general config from [/home/sinhau/.rviz/config]

Config file '/home/sinhau/.rviz/config' could not be opened for reading.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

I looked into the '.rviz' folder and found it to be empty.  So I have no idea what the problem is.  Some of the suggested solutions in other forums were to change the variable OGRE_RTT_MODE to either Copy,FBO, or PBuffer.  I tried all of them using export OGRE_RTT_MODE=________ and reran rviz using 'rosrun rviz rviz'.  The results were still the same.  If anybody has an idea as to what's going on, sharing it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46239/how-do-i-prevent-segmentation-fault-when-starting-rviz?/) by [sinha.karsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3409/sinha.karsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will be the graphics card. If you're lucky you need to install the proprietory ATI or NVidia drivers. The best choice is to use a computer with an NVidia gaming 3D graphics card, you will have less problems  :-)

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1